# PHP shows newest comment from mysql without refreshing the page.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to reach a function like twitter. When people add a comment in my site anywhere. The newest information will display in one part of my home page. And upload the information without refresh the home page. I think it could be done by ajax, but I am a newbie, can anyone give me a live demo? or introduce me some plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good start for jquery: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-jquery-spy-effect/

Then your ajax call will simply need to get the latest comments from your database. Probably by timestamp or datetime

Comment: Thanks, I have some plungin like `Digg Spy`, But I do not know how to use ajax compleate to get a latest comments from my database. Do you have any demo or tutorial of this?

Answer (score -1):

There is a good example and study material for ajax

> ```
> http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_example.asp
> ```